# fortran multi processor

Tags: multithreading, fortran90

i have written a code using fortran 90.

but when i run it it uses only one core from 8 cores of the CPU

is there a way to employ all the core of the CPU to run a fortran program?
Kind Regrads,

btw, running on WINXP

---

edit
compiler:
Microsoft Workstation power station

Comment: Which compiler/runtime are we talking about?

Comment: Yes there is. But it is a -process- between, and some introductory text would be a valuable read to get you started. Also, it depends on the problem you're trying to solve as well, whether those gains would be worthwhile.

Comment: Microsoft Workstation power station

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are indeed ways of designing Fortran programs to use all the cores on a multicore processor. Investigate [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) and [MPI](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/).  How easy these are with what is now an old and outdated compiler I don't know.